# Setting custom font inside `ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter`

Tags: android, gridview, fonts, adapter

I am using `ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter` to inflate a `gridview`. Gridview has two `textview`s. I want to set custom font for one of them. Using `Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BABYCAKE.TTF");` in `ImageAdapter` gives error `The method getAssets() is undefined for the type ImageAdapter`.

`ImageAdapter` is defined as

```
package com.amit.wozzle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{  
private ArrayList<String> listCountry;  
private ArrayList<String> scorestage;  
private Activity activity;  
Typeface font;

public ImageAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<String> listCountry, ArrayList<String> scorestage) {  
    super();  
    this.listCountry = listCountry;  
    this.scorestage = scorestage;  
    this.activity = activity;  
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "BABYCAKE.TTF");
}  

@Override  
public int getCount() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return listCountry.size();  
}  

@Override  
public String getItem(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return listCountry.get(position);  
}  

@Override  
public long getItemId(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return 0;  
}  

public static class ViewHolder  
{  
    public ImageView imgViewFlag;  
    public TextView  txtViewTitle; 
    public TextView  txtViewTitle2; 
}  

@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    ViewHolder view;  
    LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();  

    if(convertView==null)  
    {  
        view = new ViewHolder();  
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);  
        view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
        view.txtViewTitle2.setTypeface(font);
        view.txtViewTitle2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);  

        // view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
        convertView.setTag(view);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }  
    // view.txtViewTitle2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    view.txtViewTitle2.setText(listCountry.get(position)); 
    view.txtViewTitle.setText(scorestage.get(position)); 
    // view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(scorestage.get(position));  

    return convertView;  
}  
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "BABYCAKE.TTF");
```

Comment: i tried this, kindly see the code above. getting nullpointer error at the line `view.txtViewTitle2.setTypeface(font);` in `getView` method. Font file does exist, I am using it in other activities.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating `Typeface` object inside `getView`. `Typeface` takes lot of memory and it will slow down your app as less memory space will be available due to number of Typeface objects created inside `getView`.

Instead Font file should be created only one time and reused when needed. Create font file outside of `getView`. Declare it as an instance variable inside your adapter if you use it only inside adapter and initialise it inside your adapter constructor. And instead of creating new instance each time inside getView use that single instance to set font.

And for your error use activity instance variable to call `getAssests()`

```
TypeFace font = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/BABYCAKE.TTF");
```

**Edit-**
Try to use it like this-

```
class DemoFonts{
    private static TypeFace typeFace;   
    public static TypeFace getTypeFace(Context mContext){
        if(typeface==null){
            typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/BABYCAKE.TTF");
        }

        return typeface;
    }

}
```

Try to use like above. Assuming that you have `fonts` folder inside assets folder.

Comment: did the change as per ur suggestion.

Comment: Yeah now looks good. Also if you are using that typeface somewhere else also you can declare it as static variable inside some utility class and use it everywhere.

Comment: could u please explain how to do it. i am using it in other activities

Comment: I have modify my answer please check. Also if you have any folder inside assets folder in which you have placed font file use that folder name while making font file like my code.

Comment: `demofont` will be inner class or it will be new java class. if it is a new class then can i use variable `typeface` in any activity directly ?

Comment: You can name it any name you want and either create new class or if you have any class in which you have declared your static global variables you can declare the content of demofont class inside that. And to use typeface just call static getTypeFace method passing context and it will return you Typeface object.

Answer (score 1):

view.txtViewTitle2 giving null pointer exception because you are trying to access textView before initializing. Below changes should work properly

```
view.txtViewTitle2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)
view.txtViewTitle2.setTypeface(font);
```